# simplest way to create EditText like a Rectangular box?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am creating a sample browser for myself,in which url is set by a edit text that's why i want a edit text must look like a rectangular box like in other browsers...help me out guys???

Comment: ... is giving it a rectangular Drawable shape as a background not enough?

Comment: Are you asking how to edit the width/height of the edittext?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Example]

Add this line to the edittext:

```
android:background="@drawable/edittext_frame"
```

And this edittext_frame.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/primary_light" />
    <padding android:left="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: is dere's any way to get rectangular box by adding xml code inside main.xml ie our mainlayout file.